# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): history.go is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error when I am using the go() method on the const history storing the useNavigate() hook... How to resolve this error and redirect the page to another browser on a click event

```
const history = useNavigate()

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // default action of form submission is to refresh the page

    const blog = {
        title,
        body,
        author
    }

    setIsPending(true)
    // should work only after the handleSubmit() event occurs
    
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(blog)
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('New blog added')
        setIsPending(false)
        history.go(-1)
    })
}
```

This is the code I tried and the error displyed in the browser window is 'Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): history.go is not a function'

Answer (score 0):

`useNavigate` is not a hook provided by React. You are probably using react-router and should be consulting this documentation: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate. The returned object indeed doesn't have a `go` function (unlike the browser native `history` object that you are probably thinking of).